# VB.NET SQL query resultset different

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am reading data from SQL into my vb.net program and am getting incorrect data when I run the application. As such I have simplified my query to diagnose and when I run the code on my SQL management studio I get 2288 results but when I run the same code in my application I am only getting 1872 results.

SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM invoiceItem 
left join invoice on invoice.invoiceno = invoiceitem.invoiceno
where invoice.customer = 'aaapal'
```

VB.NET Code

```
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT * FROM invoiceItem " & _
        "left join invoice on invoice.invoiceno = invoiceitem.invoiceno " & _
        "WHERE invoice.customer = 'aaapal'"
Dim DT As New DataTable
Try
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TSMT_DBConnectionString)
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(SQL, con)
    da.Fill(DT)
    MessageBox.Show(DT.Rows.Count)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Error Loading top 10 Products", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try

Return DT
```

Any suggestions as to what could be causing this issue?

Comment: My guess would be that you're not looking at the same databases.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the same query?

Comment: How do you know the app has that many rows? Do you count them in code or do you display them on screen and count them manually? I suggest you use SQL Profiler to capture the SQL statement then run it and check record count. This would also tell you if you're connecting to the wrong db. You could also try and identify which rows are missing (i.e. by ordering them and find the first non matching row).

Comment: Thank, that was a really blond moment. I had the connection string set correctly in my application settings, but was overriding it to access a test database that was 1 month old.